# Reactjs redux store changes but in component's props doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

> I'm tryin to show navigation depends on changes of categoryURL from
>   redux store and changing the state in other components. Redux changes the store and it works fine. But in my
>   component "this.props.categoryUrl" doesn't reflect on value. Can't
>   find out why?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import NavigationItems from './NavigationItems/NavigationItems';
import classes from './Navigation.module.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        categoryURL: state.categoryUrl
    };
};

class navigation extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.categoryUrl);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        console.log('NAVIGATION!', this.props.categoryUrl);
    }

    render() {
        let nav = null;
        if (this.props.categoryUrl) {
            nav = (
                    <div className={classes.Navigation}>
                        <NavigationItems/>
                    </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <>
                {nav}
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(navigation);
```

Comment: Typo - should be `this.props.categoryURL` according to your `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "normal" React it is needed to use `<Navigation/>` (Capital letter at the beginning) instead of `<navigation/>`. Also, If `<Navigation/>` is being used by another React component then it might be needed to add code that will be executed inside `<Navigation/>` to refresh the component where you are using `<Navigation/>` (some kind of callback passed to `<Navigation/>`). It is this the way or move all the `<Navigation/>`'s code to the component where you are using `<Navigation/>`. This is how I solved this kind of problem.